# Javax net SSL sslhandshakeexception Remote host terminated the handshake

Tags: java, email, ssl, jakarta-mail, pop3

I'm trying to create a Java application that only receives emails from my private email (not gmail), but I keep getting errors, whether it's a connection failed or SSL handshake problems, the last error I got is:

> Javax net SSL sslhandshakeexception Remote host terminated the handshake.

My java class is :

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class CheckingMail {

  public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user,
                           String password)
  {
    try {

      //create properties field
      Properties properties = new Properties();

      properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
      properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
      properties.put("mail.pop3s.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
      properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.ssl.trust", "*"); // Trust all Servers
      properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.ssl.trust", "private hostname"); // Trust all Servers
      Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
      Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

      store.connect(host, user, password);

      //create the folder object and open it
      Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
      emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

      // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
      Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
      System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

      for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
        Message message = messages[i];
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
        System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
        System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
        System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());

      }

      //close the store and folder objects
      emailFolder.close(false);
      store.close();

    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String host = "private host name";// change accordingly
    String mailStoreType = "pop3";
    String username = "my email";// change accordingly
    String password = "my password";// change accordingly


    check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);

  }

}
```

Comment: You're configuring the `mail.pop3.*` properties, while connecting with the `pop3s` protocol. If you want to connect with `pop3s`, you should use the `mail.pop3s.*` properties.

Comment: I changed it but i still get the same error remote host terminated the handshake